# change the selected value of a dropdownlist inside nested repeater

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, datasource, selectedvalue

I tried to change a dropdownlist selected value from a c# code :

```
<repeater >
   <repeater> 
      <dropdown>
```

and I add a datasource in aspx page to the dropdown
every thing works fine .. but I want to change the selected value onload of the dropdown
to be able to show the user the previous selected name when edit the table

```
protected void PrepairDropDownList(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        shiftrepeater.DataBind();
        if (shiftrepeater.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int shiftcount = 0; shiftcount < shiftrepeater.Items.Count; shiftcount++)
            {
                Repeater temp = (Repeater)shiftrepeater.Items[shiftcount].FindControl("saturdayrepeater");
                if (temp.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int count = 0; count < temp.Items.Count; count++)
                    {
                        DropDownList ds = (DropDownList)temp.Items[count].FindControl("userdropdown");
                        HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)temp.Items[count].FindControl("hiddenid");//contain the id if the field 
                        SarcShiftUser user = CRUD<SarcShiftUser>.Get(int.Parse(hf.Value)); //a method to select a user with a specific id and add it to object from class sarcshiftuser

                        if (user.id == 0)
                            ds.SelectedValue = "";
                        else
                        {
                            ds.SelectedValue = user.user_id + "";

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        shiftrepeater.DataBind();
    }
```

I add this method to Onload of the repeater :
but nothing change and the previous name didn't show

P.S : the user object is correct and the user.user_id is also correct
P.S 2 : I tried to add a ds.DataBind(); after changing the selected but give that error :

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'userdropdown' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
```

Comment: Not sure where to start from, how do you bind/populate your drop down? Does your dropdown has the value that is [user.user_id + ""]?

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="userdropdownds" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:samy_sarc %>" SelectCommand="select id, firstname + ' ' + lastname as name from sarcuser"></asp:SqlDataSource>


value : <%#Eval("id")%>
text : <%#Eval("name")%>

Answer (score 0):

Safest way to set `SelectedItem` of a `DropdownList` is to set the `SelectedIndex` like this:

```
ds.SelectedIndex = ds.Items.IndexOf(ds.Items.FindByValue(user.user_id.ToString()));
```

Comment: still not working ... it takes the value correct in the two way ... but it didn't change so the selected value still empty

Comment: @Samy Sammour - make sure that `DataValueField` of the `DropDownList` is set to `user_id` or something that represents `user_id`.

Comment: I'm sure about that but I guess the problem is when I got the dropdown from the repeater it's make a copy not take the real one

Comment: @Samy Sammour - It is working for me. You can check the test project I have used: [NestedRepeaterTest](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0cldOZnV4bkMtWlk/edit?usp=sharing).