# dropdown menu inside the repeater in shift table asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to build a shift table in asp.net

I use a mainrepeater for the shift and a repeater inside for the people in shift

```
<repeater .... shift 1 - 2 - 3 .... >
   <repeater .... person 1 - 2 - 3 inside each shift >
      <dropdown .... to select the person name >
```

---

### shift 1

repeater_dropdown1
repeater_dropdown2
.
.

### .

### shift 2

repeater_dropdown1
repeater_dropdown2
..
.
.
etc

every thing works fine and the save is ok

but the problem is when I edit the shift table .
because I can add a 3 person now and after unspecific time add the other

so the drop down list should get the last user_id and select the value of it 
I tried this code onload of the main repeater

```
protected void PrepareDropDownList(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Repeater repeater = (Repeater)sender;
        if (repeater.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int shiftcount = 0; shiftcount < repeater.Items.Count; shiftcount++)
            {
                Repeater temp = (Repeater)repeater.Items[shiftcount].FindControl("saturdayrepeater");
                if (temp.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int count = 0; count < temp.Items.Count; count++)
                    {
                        DropDownList ds = (DropDownList)temp.Items[count].FindControl("userdropdown");
                        HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)temp.Items[count].FindControl("hiddenid");
                        SarcShiftUser user = CRUD<SarcShiftUser>.Get(int.Parse(hf.Value)); //a method to select a user with a specific id and add it to object from class sarcshiftuser

                        //ds.SelectedValue = user.user_id+"";
                        //ds.DataBind();
                        //err.Text += ds.SelectedValue + "<br />";
                        //if (user.id != 0)
                        //{
                        //    ds.SelectedIndex = ds.Items.IndexOf(ds.Items.FindByValue(user.user_id.ToString()));
                        //}

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

but it didn't work it takes the id correct and every thing is fine but dropdownlist didn't 
show the selected value ... i guess the wrong of it is because the findcontrol takes a copy of the dropdown not the exact one ...

plz help to repair this code or to find another solution ?

Comment: 1. You shoun't repost same question. 2.In your question add your markup of the repeaters 3. Repeater's `onload` is not the best place to set value of it's dropdownlist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [change the selected value of a dropdownlist inside nested repeater](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968178/change-the-selected-value-of-a-dropdownlist-inside-nested-repeater)

Answer (score 0):

I used the tooltip attribute and call this function :

```
protected void PrepareDropDownList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList list = (DropDownList)sender;
        int i = int.Parse(list.ToolTip);
        "select the user_id where id ...." = id
        list.SelectedValue = user.user_id + "";
    }

<asp:DropDownList ID="userdropdown" CssClass="select" runat="server" OnDataBound="PrepareDropDownList" ToolTip='<%#Eval("repeaterid") %>' />
```

it's worked